# CakePHP find query across multiple datasources

Tags: cakephp, orm

I am tring to do the following:

- My 'Company' Models are being stored in a 'default' datasource. In to
  model I set the var $useDbConfig = 'default';
- My 'User' Models are being stored in another datasource called
  'users_db'. In this model I set the var $useDbConfig = 'users_db';

There is a 'belongsTo' relationship between 'Company' and 'User' models.

I want to do a recursive find query that brings back all users for each company in one go. I have the feeling that I cannot do this with Cake as it currently is.

When I try the following:

```
$res2 = $this->Company->find('all', array(
                'conditions' => array('Company.id' => 1),
                'recursive'=>2
            ));
```

I get a message that it cannot find the users table(its looking in the default source):
Error: Table user_groups for model User was not found in datasource **default**.

Is there any way I can do this?

Many thanks for any help you can provide.....

kSeudo.

Comment: 1) what are your associations?, 2) using recursive is not idea - try CakePHP's Containable behavior instead.  Then, if it still doesn't work, post the query it's trying to run.

Comment: hi Dave,
Thanks for the response.
- User Model belongsTo Company
- Company Model hasMany Users

The query is as defined above. The big problem is that Company and User models are stored in different databases. Do you think that I can still use a find query to pull back the full result with the relationships intact?

I will look to see if 'Containable' can help me.

Many thanks!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I believe Cake handles multi-db queries fine.  What you're showing in your question is not the query - that's the CakePHP line of code that MAKES the query.  It would help greatly for you to edit your question and add the actual generated query.

Comment: Apologies Dave I know what you mean now....
The problem is that if I run the cake query with recursive set to 2 the query will not run and I cannot see the SQL in DebugKit.

Comment: Get rid of the recursive parameter and instead put in `'contain' => array('User')`. This way cake is likely to run two separate queries and combine the output into a single array.

Comment: Ok apologies, I was missing a foreign key column in my Users table :(. It appear to be working now.... thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

Why not replace the your original statement by this:

```
$this->loadModel('User');
$res2 = $this->User->find('all', 
                array( 'conditions' => array( 'User.company_id' => 1 ) ));
```

This will produce the results you want.

Otherwise, if you wanted something tidier, you could add a `fetch_users()` function to your `Company` class that implemented a similar logic.

Answer (score 0):

---

Ok, problem solved. Once I set the datasource in the model correctly everything seems to work fine.

Thanks guys

Comment: Adding to this answer how to set a data source will make this answer better and [accept your answer as well. Accepted answers make this community a better place](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/150789)